# How to identify when my session variable is changed?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, session, session-variables

I am having a session variable whose value can be changed from java and from Jsp as well. Is it possible to detect when this variable's value is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) and you will get notification every time the value is replaced. Notice that in the following cases (which is highly not recommended) it won't work:

```
MyObject myobj = (MyObject)session.getAttribute("obj");
myobj.setValue(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html).